# Generate SHA256 fingerprint from RSA public key (string only)

Tags: rsa, keys, sha-256

I have the public key, the string itself (not a file), and I am trying to figure out the SHA256 fingerprint, as in the image attached. The default key generated by PuttyGen is SSH-2 RSA with a SHA256 fingerprint. This would help me identify the keys by their fingerprints in the AWS S3 containers, given that I stored only the public keys during the setup of the file transferring protocols. A Windows applicable solution is preferred please (cmd or Python).

[image: PuttyGen- Public Key & Fingerprint]

Comment: Software recommendations are not really our field. If you want to find out the key fingerprint of SSH works then you can ask that, preferably after reading the SSH specifications. Please take a look at [this info](https://superuser.com/questions/421997) first.

Comment: AWS uses a custom fingerprint format IIRC.